# Lucene index corruption

Tags: lucene, indexing

I've had a serious problem with several clients while utilising a Lucene search index where anomalies like content missing that should be there or duplicate content (more than one document of the same content item that both have the `islatest` flag).  In many cases an index rebuild will fix it, but more often than not a rebuild will simply shuffle around the anomalies.

Ultimately I'm asking is there a way to configure the search index to be more consistent and reliable?

Note that I'm specifically talking about the `sitecore_master_index` and `sitecore_web_index`.

Comment: Have you checked into the tables for publishing and events? Sometimes these tables become very large. Perhaps you can perform a cleanup on the tables and then ensure the agents run more frequently. More details can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24192678/sitecore-eventqueue-table-growing-out-of-control

Comment: The details you have provided in your question are not enough to understand your issue. Please edit your question and include additional information, such as: Is the index a standard one or a custom one? If it's custom, include its configuration and custom code. Specify which fields have missing/duplicate values. Is your site multi-language? Does your index use all item languages? Etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have implemented several search based sites on top of the Lucene provider, and for me the system is consistent and reliable. When I have had that sort of problems with the index in the past it was due to two reasons:

- The scope of my SearchContent: I was reusing it too much, meaning my results were not updated, even when the actual index was. As the index was constantly updated, I had to call Index.CreateSearchContent each time I had to search.
- Obsolete items in the index: I managed to fix it following this [KB](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/992608)

Comment: KB 992608 fixed my issue.

Comment: Great to see that you fixed your problem. Could you please mark the answer as solution?

Answer (score 6):

If it is a custom config then it should also contain the `_uniqueid` field.

```xml
<field fieldName="_uniqueid" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
    <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
</field>
```

It looks like that it is problem. Because when you rebuild the index then it doesn't care about existing entries in the index, it just rebuild it. In the other cases it needs the `_uniqueid` to find in the index.

Here you can find a detailed blog post about it: https://trnktms.wordpress.com/2016/09/29/duplicate-entries-in-lucene-index-after-item-publishsave